# Do Upstart job configuration files have their own variables?

Tags: upstart

There is a lot of discussion about how environment variables work in upstart, and that they aren't available to the upstart job configuration.  Do upstart job configurations have their own form of variable to do something like:

```
...
myworkingdir=/opt/specialpackage
chdir $myworkingdir

exec $myworkingdir/bin/executable1 run-program $myworkingdir/bin/executable2 param1 param2
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not available in Job Configuration File. All job processes are children of *init* which does not have a user's environment. [Init](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?init%208) is parent of all processes.

However, environment variables could be set in Job Configuration File and it is possible to pass variables from a user environment to job.

It is possible to define variables in form `myworkingdir=/opt/specialpackage` but such variable will be available only in the section in which it is defined.

For details check [Environment Variables](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables).